# How to transform an array to an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> Your task is to add the missing logic to a `transformToObjects()`
> function that transforms a list of numbers into a list of JavaScript
> objects.
>
> For the provided input `[1, 2, 3]` the `transformToObjects()` function
> should return `[{val: 1}, {val: 2}, {val: 3}]`.

Is it possible to have different values for a same key in JavaScript?

I tried to use the map method of array, but it was giving the output as undefined.

```
function transformToObjects(numberArray) {
   const obj = numberArray.map(({element}) => ({ ['val'] : element }));
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `transformToObjects` doesn't return anything, and `obj` _is_ undefined outside it. Also numbers don't have an `element` property to destructure.

Comment: This sounds like it is probably some school work, which if it is is unethical to simply ask for someone to give you a solution.

Comment: "Unethical" is an weird exaggeration. At least the OP has attempted to solve the problem which you often don't get with these questions.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is you're on the right track. `map` is a good choice of array method because it's *transformative* - the callback operates on each element in turn and returns an array *of the same length* as the one you're processing.

One thing the tasks mentions is that the *function* returns the array which you're currently not doing.

You don't need to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the element (`.map(({element}) =>`  should just be `.map(element =>`), and you don't need to put the object key in square brackets - you're thinking of [computed property names](https://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript) which isn't needed here.

Finally you need to call the function with the array as an argument, and log its returned value.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

function transformToObjects(numberArray) {

  // Return the result of calling `map` on the array
  // (which is itself an array)
  return numberArray.map(element => {
    return { val: element };
  });
}

// Call the function with the array as an argument
// and log its returned value
console.log(transformToObjects(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to destructure anything when mapping over the array, unless your `element` field holds the number. Also, you need to return the mapping.

Since your input array contains only numbers, the first argument in the `Array.prototype.map` call should be the number itself. I refer to this value as `n` in the example below.

Also, your `val` key does not have to be surrounded in brackets/quotes, since it is a literal identifier in the object.

```js
const transformToObjects = (numberArray) => numberArray.map((n) => ({ val: n }));

console.log(transformToObjects([1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your attempt with the map function, obj is undefined outside the scope of your function. Also, that is not the proper syntax for using Array.map, check out the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You also say the function should return the new array but your function does not return anything.

This might make a bit more sense for you:

```
function transformToObjects(numberArray) {
    //Create a new array
    let newArray = []
    
    //Loop for each element in the first array
    for (let index = 0; i < numberArray.length; index++) {
        //Create the new Object 
        let obj = {'val': index}

        //Append it to the new array
        newArray.push(obj)
    }

    //Return the new array
    return newArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transformToObjects(numberArray) {
    return numberArray.map((item) => ({val : item}));
}
```

the simplest solution